# Drinking non-alcoholic beer at work

Tags: professionalism

Personally I don't like the stuff, but I was wondering what the implications would be?

Obviously it's non-alcoholic so not against company policy and doesn't break any rules. But it smells like beer, looks like beer (bad if any clients are visiting) and might raise eyebrows?

Is the fact that it can be mistaken for an unsuitable product cause for it to become an unsuitable product?

Oh how philosophical...

**UPDATE:** I'm in the UK and the non-alcoholic beer here is advertised as being 0.03% - 0.05% alcohol (I checked the ones in my local supermarket). There is one marketed as 0.0% but I think they're rounding down to one decimal place. However, as the answers have pointed out, the fact that there is any alcohol at all probably makes this question redundant.

Comment: Actually it does contain a small amount of alcohol.  Typically up up 0.5% alcohol and still be called alcoholic-beer. For example in my state it cannot be sold to someone under drinking age.

Comment: @Paparazzi I didn't realise that - I just checked and the alcohol level of the ones sold here in the UK are around 0.03% vol but even one listed as 0.00% vol still has a minimum purchase age of 18

Comment: @Paparazzi You and OP may both find this wiki article interesting: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-alcohol_beer

Comment: I'm just curious since you said you don't even like the stuff. Why are you considering drinking it at work, seeing as you don't even like it?

Comment: I am curious, how the question arose.  Is somebody at work requesting authorization to drink near-beer?

Comment: @Brandin I'm not, I was just pondering the subject when I saw it in the supermarket and was wondering about it

Comment: @Lumberjack Just curious that's all, thought it would be an interesting question

Comment: Interesting question. Now would anyone complain if I were to drink a lot of kombucha?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Not if you share it ;)

Comment: Note that fruit juice also contains "some alcohol". I don't think it's a redundant question. as a glas of orange juice can also contain comparable amounts of alcohol to some non-alcoholic beers. (And I don't think anyone would complain about someone drinking orange juice at work)

Comment: @Erik Do you have to be drinking age to buy orange juice where you live?

Comment: @Paparazzi, no, but neither do you have to be drinking age to buy alcohol free beer here.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your job responsibilities and the jurisdiction, it may be forbidden by law.

For example, in the state where I live, the law makes no special allowance for "non-alcoholic" beer.  While it is classified under definitions as "immitation liquor" it is still subject to all of the liquor laws.  You must be 21 years old to purchase, driving with an open container is illegal, etc.

The laws governing alcohol in the US state of Maine are contained in Title 28-A of the Maine Revised Statutes.  Subsection 2 (Definitions) defines Alcohol as follows.

> 2. Alcohol.  "Alcohol" means the substance known as ethyl alcohol, hydrated oxide of ethyl or spirit of wine which is commonly produced
>      by the fermentation or distillation of grain, starch, molasses, sugar,
>      potatoes or other substances, and includes all dilutions and mixtures
>      of these substances.

In some occupations it is illegal to consume alcohol while on the job, and in many companies it is forbidden by policy.

Conversely in less formal companies, although it is far from commonplace, you may find yourself in a more relaxed environment where the boss encourages you to have an actual beer at the end of a long day.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it does contain a small amount of alcohol. Typically up to 0.5% alcohol and still be called non-alcoholic beer. For example in my state it cannot be sold to someone under drinking age.  It is more than a trivial amount of alcohol.

The typical process (fermentation) produces alcohol.  Since water and alcohol are azeotropes you cannot get much less than 0.5% without get exotic.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39561/discussion-on-answer-by-paparazzi-drinking-non-alcoholic-beer-at-work).